# How to start a HTML 5 video from a particular position in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, html5-video

i new start a video in a specific position when the web is loading, i get the position using a eloquent var coming from the controler. 
I also use jquery for other functions in the same view. 
I have checked the variables arrive correctly so I do not know where is the error.

The strange thing is this method only works if I show a alert popup before in firefox. (not work in chrome or other browser).

This is my code:

```
    <video id="video" style="display:none; width:100%; height:100%;" autoplay>
              <source src="/files/convert/videos/{{$moviesNow->url}}" type="video/mp4" />
              Su navegador no soporta el tag video.
    </video>

<script>
          var vid = document.getElementById("video");
          var time = {{$difTime}};
          var isPlaying = {{$playNow}};
          var moviesArr = [];
       };      
          var j = jQuery.noConflict();

          j(document).ready(function() {

            if(time >= 0 && isPlaying == 1){
                //vid.currentTime = time;

              }
            });
function setCurTime() { 
              vid.currentTime = time;
            };
</script>
```

Also i trying use:

```
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
          this.currentTime = time;
        }, false);
```

But the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

The `loadedmetadata` event is helpful, but it doesn't ensure that the section of video you are trying to access is seekable yet. You could try a simpler solution using [Media Fragments](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/):

Just add `#t=120` to the end of the video url to have it auto-forward to that spot. Like this:

```css
video {
  height: 180px;
  width: 320px;
}
```

```html
<video src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4#t=120" controls autoplay></video>
```